# funcao FILE em C

Tags: c

o que preciso que seja feito: desenvolver um algoritmo onde calcula apartir de valores de entrada de arquivo .txt ou valores digitados pelo usuario, um valor em porcentagem que fique fora do permitido, no caso +-3 para todos os casos, onde o programa realiza uma media e compara valor por valor se esta dentro ou fora do esperado, o que esta fora ele deverá, mostrar o resultado em porcentagem do que ficou fora do esperado;

Até o momento, eu realizei isso:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
//decalara entrada de file.txt
float file_ent[]={0};
//declara saida de file.txt 
float saida;

// declara entrada de temperatura 
float vetor[15000]={0};
//declara contador e entrada de menu
int ent, ent_aux, cont,/* cont_aux,*/ cont_ex /*, cont_out*/;
//declara saida onde apresenta resultado obtido
float ex, cont_out, cont_aux,media;
//variaveis para log-in
int num_key;

//cabecalho inicial insercao de senha
do
{
    puts("\n\n\t*********************************************");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*     Calculador de temperatura             *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*          DIGITE SUA SENHA                 *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*  DIGITE 0 PARA SAIR                       *");
    puts("\t*********************************************");
    scanf("%i",&num_key);
    if(num_key == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (num_key!= 123456)
    {
        printf(" TENTE NOVAMENTE ");
    }


}while(num_key!=123456);

//cabecalho de escolha de entrada de arquivo ou digitacao
do
{
    puts("\n\n\t*********************************************");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*     Calculador de temperatura             *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*       Escolha entre importar o arquivo    *");
    puts("\t* ou digitar manualmente os valores, caso   *");
    puts("\t* digite 1 (SIM) para importar e 0 (NAO)    *");
    puts("\t* para nao importar o arquivo.              *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*     Lembrando que o arquivo deve estar    *");
    puts("\t* nomeado como \"entrada.txt\"                *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*                                           *");
    puts("\t*  DIGITE 0 PARA SAIR                       *");
    puts("\t*********************************************");
    scanf("%i",&num_key);

    // importar o arquivo para o programa
    if(num_key == 1)
    {
        printf(" VOCE OPTOU POR IMPORTAR O ARQUIVO ");

        FILE *file_ent;
        file_ent = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
        for(cont=0;file_ent != NOF; cont++)
        {
            fscanf("%f",&file_ent);
        }
    }

    // nao importar e digitar manualmente
    if (num_key== 0)
    {

    }

    // caso nao 1 e caso nao 0
    if((num_key!=1) && (num_key!=0))
    {
        printf(" ***  OPCAO INVALIDA  ***");
    }


}while((num_key!=1) && (num_key!=0));



do
{
//cabecalho
puts("\n\n\t*********************************************");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t*     Calculador de temperatura             *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t*        Calculador de temperatura          *");
puts("\t* mostrando somente a porcentagem de desvio *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t* SELECIONE UMA OPCAO DESEJADA:             *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t* 1           3 graus celcius               *");
puts("\t* 2          -3 graus celcius               *");
puts("\t* 3          -5 graus celcius               *");
puts("\t* 4          -8 graus celcius               *");
puts("\t* 5         -12 graus celcius               *");
puts("\t* 6         -15 graus celcius               *");
puts("\t* 7         -18 graus celcius               *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t* Digite 66 para sair                       *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t*  Caso erre algum valor no meio digite 999 *");
puts("\t*  onde abrira alguma opcoes para alterar o *");
puts("\t*   que voce errou. Apenas siga os passos   *");
puts("\t*                                           *");
puts("\t* Selecione uma opcao:                      *");
puts("\t*********************************************");

//le valor digitado e atribui a ent
scanf("%i",&ent);
//se ent == 0 programa finaliza
if(ent==66)
{
    return 0;
}

// se entrada for numeros de 1 a 7 entra no codigo
if((ent==1)||(ent==2)||(ent==3)||(ent==4)||(ent==5)||(ent==6)||(ent==7))
{           
//mostar opcao selecionada  
printf("\nVOCE SELECIONOU A OPCAO: %i\n\n",ent);

/*
laço for onde cont menor ou igual a 15000
ele repete ate o contador atingir valor desejado
*/

for (cont; cont<=15000;cont++)
{
    printf("Digite os valores de temperaturas desejadas: ");
    printf(" INDICIE: %i :   ",cont);
    cont_aux=cont;
    cont_ex=cont;       
    ex=ex+cont;                     

    /*
    le os valores do usuario e atribui ao vetor na variavel 
    escolhida pelo contador (cont)

    juntamente compara se for zero cai fora da operacao dando fim ao algoritmo

    caso o usuario tenha digitado algum valor errado
    ele podera alterar este valor e corrigir 
    conforme sua necessidade
    */

    scanf("%f",&vetor[cont]);
    if(vetor[cont]==66)
    {
        cont--;
        break;
    }   
    if(vetor[cont]==999)
    {
    // cabeçalho correcao de valor por indicie
    puts("\n\n\t***********************************************");
    puts("\t*             -- ATENCAO --                   *");
    puts("\t*    Neste momento voce pode altar algum      *");
    puts("\t* valor que foi digitado errado, preste       *");
    puts("\t* muita atencao no indicie do valor desejado  *");
    puts("\t* e siga os passos para que possamos auxuliar *");
    puts("\t* na correcao do mesmo                        *");
    puts("\t*                                             *");
    puts("\t*                                             *");
    puts("\t*                                             *");
    puts("\t*                                             *");
    puts("\t*     Digite o valor do indicie desejado:     *");
    puts("\t*                                             *");
    puts("\t* Digite 66 para sair                         *");
    puts("\t***********************************************");              
    // le entrada
    scanf("%i",&cont);
    printf("  Voce digitou o indicie: %i",cont);
    printf("  Digite o novo valor para este indicie: ");
    //le o indicie do valor errado
    scanf("%i",&vetor[cont]);
    printf("\n\t *** CONTINUANDO ***\n");
    //contador principal recebe ultimo contador armazenado por auxiliar
    cont=cont_aux;  
    /*
    decrementa em 1 o contador para repor o valor aonde foi digitado 
    o numero magico para alterar o valor errado e continuar de onde parou
    */
    cont--;                             
    }       
    if (vetor[cont]==66)
    {
        cont=15002;
    }           
}
//cabecalho de entrada de temperatura
puts("\n\n\t***********************************************");
puts("\t*                                             *");
puts("\t*     Apos digitar todos os valores desejados *");
puts("\t* vamos prosseguir com mais alguns passos     *");
puts("\t*     Primeiramente voce devera entrar com o  *");
puts("\t* valor da temperatura em questao que deseja  *");
puts("\t* calcular.                                   *");
puts("\t*                                             *");
puts("\t*     Digite a temperatura desejada           *");
puts("\t*                                             *");
puts("\t* Digite 66 para sair                         *");
puts("\t***********************************************");
scanf("%i",&ent_aux);
/*
para contador de 0 ate auxiliar aque recebe ultimo valor de contador
faça, contador + 1 no laço comparando se os valores do vetor forem maior
ou menor do que 3 acrescenta +1 no contador de saida com objetivo calcular
qual a porcentagem que ficou fora do calculado 
*/
for(cont=0;cont<=cont_aux;cont++)
{
    if((vetor[cont]>(ent_aux-3))&&(vetor[cont]<(ent_aux+3)))
    {
        cont_out++;
    }
    /*else
        {
            cont_out++;
        }*/
}

//calcula resultado
cont_out*100;
ex=cont_out/cont_aux;
ex=ex*100;

/*                      
//calcula media de temperatura
for(cont=0;cont<=cont_aux;cont++)
{
    media=vetor[cont]+media;
}
cont--;
media=media/cont;
media=media/2;
*/

//imprime em tela o resultado final
printf("\n\t\nVOCE OBETEVE: %.2f porcento dentro do esperado\n\n",ex);
//printf("\n\t\nMEDIA DE TEMPERATURA: %.2f",media);
}

// caso a entrada nao seja um valor de 1 a 7 imprime mensagem   
else
{
    printf ("\n\n\tValor invalido!\n\n");
}

//zera os valores dos contadores a cada fim de programa
cont=0;
cont_aux=0;
cont_out=0;

}while (ent!=66);
return 0;
}
```

até onde ia meu conhecimento eu fiz boa parte, apenas preciso que em alguns momentos o usuario entre com os determinados valores, e em outros ele possa importar um arquivo .txt com nome de "entrada.txt" e no final do calculo retorne "saida.txt" com o resultado final e em alguns momentos, ele possa entrar com valores manualmente.

ate um ponto eu tentei declara um FILE mas nao sei bem como faz, e por fim nao funcionou! peço que me ajudem e me expliquem como proceder.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, sua dúvida não ficou muito precisa quanto ao seu problema.

Porém, levando em consideração seu último parágrafo, o erro contido onde você quer importar o arquivo para o programa é o seguinte:

1. Possui duas declarações de variáveis iguais `file_ent`. Uma sendo um vetor `float` e outra sendo `FILE *`.
2. A função `fscanf` recebe como 1o argumento o poteiro `FILE*` e o resto dos parâmetros seguem iguais ao `scanf`.
3. Caso você queira verificar se o `FILE*` já atingiu o fim do arquivo deve-se verificar com `EOF` (que significa End-of-file), também sugiro utilizar a função `feof()` - definida no cabeçalho `<stdio.h>`.

Fora isso, outros erros que aparecerão serão por conta dos erros anteriores. Por exemplo, provavelmente você quer dar um `scanf` no arquivo e armazená-lo no vetor de `float`, dessa forma, você deve indicar qual `índice do vetor` você quer passar por `referência` para a função `fscanf`.

Ademais, seu vetor de `float` `file_ent` é criado com tamanho 1, tendo em vista a inicialização que você fez e por não conter números nos colchetes. Caso saiba qual o tamanho do vetor é necessário para essa tarefa, ponha ele nos colchetes, senão, terá que manipulá-lo como `ponteiro` e utilizar ferramentas de `alocação dinâmica`.

Comment: mas no caso ele pode variar o valor de entrada, hoje pode ser 1000 valores amanha 15000 nunca sei exatamente, e eu vou disponibilizar para um usuario final o .exe, onde nem eu nem ele podera ficar alterando de acordo, com a entrada. Sera que se ponhasse o EOF no caso, e deixasse o vetor com [15000], nao daria certo?

Comment: Bom, tendo em vista que você quer algo dinâmico, por que não solicitar ao usuário esse tamanho no momento de execução?
Bastaria um `scanf` nesse valor e a declaração do vetor como `file_ent[variavel]`, sendo *`variavel`* o que você vai "escanear" com o scanf.